# spark buttonbar ... change label on rollover

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I've got a spark buttonbar w/ a dataprovider as follows:
'

```
   <s:ArrayCollection id="arr">  
 <s:source>  
 <fx:Object label="Dave" addr="123 Main" />  
 <fx:Object label="Brenda" addr="456 Center" /> 
</s:source>  
</s:ArrayCollection>
```

'

By default, the button's labels will be "Dave" and "Brenda", respectively. How can I dynamically change the label to the "addr" field when a user rolls over the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [mouseOver](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:mouseOver) event handler to the ButtonBar.  In the event handler do something like this:

```
buttonBar.labelField = 'addr';
```

In a [mouseOut](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:mouseOut) event handler do something like this:

```
buttonBar.labelField = 'label';
```